# Efficiency as a dependent variable

Tags: logistic, anova, chi-squared-test, generalized-linear-model

I have a dataset, consisting of two independent variables each with two levels.

The independent variables are individuals (1 vs. 2) and light (day vs. night) The dependent variable is the efficiency to detect an object (in other words the proportion of objects detected in a known population of objects). I want to find out whether there is a difference between individuals and between amount of light.

I wonder which statistical test is should use for the analysis, is it possible to use a two-way ANOVA?

Answer (score 1):

In short: **Yes**.

I find [this](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/whatstat/default.htm) table very useful in determining which statistical analysis to apply.

You have 1 dependent variable, 2 or more independent variables (independent groups), the nature of your depentant variable can probably be assumed to be normal, at least marginally, so the correct statistical analysis would indeed be **factorial** (or **two-way**) **ANOVA**.

The linked page also contains instructions on how to perform this test in STATA or SAS.

PS: Welcome to the site!

Comment: Thanks a lot mzuba! What should I do if I have an unbalanced design between the trials in which efficiency is tested? Can I still use a two-way ANOVA, or do I have to use a regression analysis?